# tools to search free text in a text document

Tags: text, nlp

I have a word document with hundreds of questions and answers I want a way to be able to search for questions not knowing the exact word used. is there any tool or existing library for searching the free text handling acronyms or different ways for asking same questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ideas:

- IR techniques are pretty good in general-domain QA, especially if your document is big. I'd index document with elasticsearch and issue queries over the index.
- If you can keep an in-memory index and computing similarity values for each query (assuming that your document is not big), I'd give a try to these phrasal and sentence-level similarities: https://github.com/CogComp/cogcomp-nlp/tree/master/similarity